# Unable to stop an invisible socket on port 80

Tags: port, httpd, socket

I want to run my Apache server but I got this error:

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I used netstat to check which process is using this port but I got no response:

```
# netstat -lnp | grep :80
#
```

In httdp.conf, if I change the listening port and the SSL port, I can correctly start my server (but it is not what I want):

```
Listen 8080
Listen 8443 https
```

I get:

```
# /usr/sbin/httpd -k start
#
```

So there is an invisible process who is running on my 80 and 443 ports and I cannot identify it. I also reboot the server and the problem continues.
Any ideas?

---

To answer to the question(s) in comments:

```
# grep -R 'Listen' /etc/httpd
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_heartmonitor.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_pagespeed_ap24.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_prefork.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_event.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_pagespeed.so matches
Binary file /etc/httpd/modules/mod_mpm_worker.so matches
/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf:Listen *:80
/etc/httpd/conf.d/mod_jk.conf:Listen *:443
/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf:Listen 443 https
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# Listen: Allows you to bind Apache to specific IP addresses and/or
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:# Change this to Listen on specific IP addresses as shown below to
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:#Listen 12.34.56.78:80
/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:Listen 80
```

Comment: Can you grep for "Listen 80" (`grep -R 'Listen 80' /etc/httpd)` to make sure you do not have it in another config file?

Comment: @Tux_DEV_NULL I added it in my post.

Comment: I would search for only the `Listen` directive, a `Listen 80` might also conflict with a `Listen <specific_ip-address>:80`

Comment: @HBruijn This time, there are "Listen" in mod_jk.conf.

Comment: @Pierre, try also with `ps -ef | grep http` and `lsof -i:80` and see if it shows something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that you have multiple [`Listen`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/bind.html) directives in your main httpd.conf and the subsections that get included from `conf.d/*.conf` and  similar.

> Overlapping Listen directives will result in a fatal error which will prevent the server from starting up.

Comment: I comment the `Listen` directives in mod_jk.conf and I can start my server now.